# can a math formula or math algorithm be patented?

Tags: math

can you patent an algorithm (math ) like it happened with PAGE RANK algorithm ??

isn't supposed that math is free for everyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't patent a mathematical algorithm by itself. It would be deemed "abstract". What you might be able to do is patent the use of an algorithm as applied to a specific task. I have a couple of patents of this sort. The usual requirements apply. The invention must be novel, non-obvious and useful. What is considered novel and non-obvious with regards to algorithm based patents has evolved over time so what might have past muster in the 1990s might not currently. Also, what is patentable may vary by country.